# Regex to match comma + newline

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression to check occurrences of `,` and the `newline` character together. I would prefer it with egrep.

**Example:**

```
strstr("Hello World","Hello");
```

should not match, and

```
strstr("Hello World",
       "Hello");
```

should return a match.

I tried both `egrep ',\n'`, and `egrep ',$'`, but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
,\r\n
```

Depending on your platform this is different

```
\r    Mac up to OS 9 
\n   UNIX/Linux, Starting from Mac OS 10 (OS X)
\r\n DOS
```

The regex

```
,$
```

Should also work, and is more universal, but remember to set the option so that $ matches at line breaks and not only the end of your entire string.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is there is either whitespace after the comma or you have the wrong type of line endings in this file. I would start with this to see if it hits. Then scale back:

```
',[ \t\l\f]*[\n\r]*'
```